# What does the phrase "all but" signify in following text?

Tags: meaning

What does the phrase "all but" mean in this sentence?

> Interpol has all but ruled out terrorism.

Comment: _All but_ means "very nearly, except for some minor details or exceptions."

Comment: With _all,_ the meaning of _but_ is normally 'except'.

Comment: *Interpol has done everything except for ruling out terrorism.*